# Wordpress Latest Blog Entries Plugin for Website

Tags: wordpress

I would like to display my blog entries on my website in an iframe or whatever suggested method is. Can somebody please advice how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The site that i want to integrate is an html site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi,**

There are multiple options to do this I am mentioning three of them:

**Menthod # 1**

You can create a page template in wordpress and than using that page template create a page. Now you have the URL you can use that page in iFrame on any website.

**Method # 2**

Create a file at the root level of the server with this code:

```
<?php
// Include WordPress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-load.php');
query_posts('showposts=1');
while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more...</a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now you can call this file in the iFrame and you have the latest posts.

**Method # 3**

You can use the rss feed from wordpress and either use PHP or jQuery to style it.

**Thanks**

**Peachlabs**